# How to increase the width of TCPDF line?

Tags: tcpdf

I'm struggling to increase the width of horizontal line in TCPDF with PHP, can someone help me to
achieve this.
I'm trying with the below code.

```
$pdf->writeHTML("<hr>",true, false, false, false,'');
```

Below is the result.
[getting this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGBeh.jpg)
I want the result like this
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBrgl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I got answer to my question on https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_012/
and worked perfectly fine.

Thanks